# How can I make the button which turns off the screen to work?

Tags: windows-10, display, button-remapping

I have Lenovo IdeaPad 310-15IAP. The upper button which is responsible for turning off the screen on the model is pretty strange. Its image is divided in two parts. I suppose it is responsible for two things, but how can I make it actually turn of the screen? Now, when I am pressing it the screen stays unaffected.

Here is the button I mean:

[image]

It is the button with <kbd>F10</kbd>. There are two symbols which are divided by a line. When I press the button I get the functionality of the right most button. I would like to get the functionality of the left most button.

And by the way all the other buttons work fine.

I suppose the button works fine as well, but I have to press something like <kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> in order to get the desired effect (<kbd>Shift+F10</kbd> does not work in the case) and I do not know what exactly I should press.

Comment: Which button are you referring to? Can you provide a photo?

Comment: @DavidPostill, please, look the edition of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's drivers. I do not suggest messing with them.

Instead get [this](http://www.deanhouseholder.com/projects/lockscreen/) AHK script. You can edit it, but by default ctrl + 6 puts your computer to lock and then screen off if you press any key. Holding f10 unlocks it.

Or you can install [this](http://download.cnet.com/Monitor-Off-Utility/3000-20432_4-10967806.html) and configure your hotkeys from the gui, tough the ahk script is better, since with the monof utility when you move your mouse by a bit, it wakes up instantly.

Comment: If you vote, then could you please type a reason in the comments for it? Just curios. Thanks.

Comment: It is not exactly what I was looking for. I would like to figure out how I can I make Lenovo upper row buttons to work. And one of the most important things is to being able to turn the light in the screen off. I up voted the answer. It was not me who down voted.